# App crashes when I launch camera to take picture on Redmi 7A. Unable to caught the crash in UncaughtException handler as well

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera, redmi-device

App crashes when I launch camera to take picture on Redmi 7A. Unable to caught the crash in UncaughtException handler as well.

After capturing image, it is staying in same screen, seems like not crashed but all the data has been cleared.

```
Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File out = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null);
        filename = (System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
        out = new File(out, filename);
        if (Build.VERSION_CODES.N <= Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
            picUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), getContext().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", out);
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, picUri);
        } else {
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(out));
        }
        getActivity().startActivityForResult(i, ConstantsUtils.CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Also used largeHeap in manifest for sufficient memory

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

And also added required features in manifest

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
    android:required="true" />
```

I'm Sorry that I didn't find any logs for this error, Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Logs should be there , if you have added try catch write printStackTrace() in catch block.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use FileProvider.FileProvider is a special subclass of ContentProvider which allows sharing of files between application through content URI instead of file:// URI.
Create an XML file(provider_path.xml)inside your res/xml folder and define it Manifest file
`<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true"> <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/> </provider>`

write the below code in your provider_path.xml file.
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <paths xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> <external-path name="external_files" path="."/> </paths>`